# Is there nontrivial structure to forcing axioms?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Suppose that $\cal P$ is a class of forcings, we denote by $\operatorname{FA}_\kappa(\cal P)$ the statement that whenever $\Bbb P\in\cal P$, $\gamma<\kappa$, and $\{D_\alpha\mid\alpha<\gamma\}$ are dense open sets in $\Bbb P$, then there is a filter $G\subseteq\Bbb P$ such that $G\cap D_\alpha\neq\varnothing$ for all $\alpha<\gamma$.

The usual examples are Martin's Axiom where $\kappa=2^{\aleph_0}$, and $\cal P$ is the class of ccc forcings; or the Proper Forcing Axiom where $\cal P$ is the class of proper forcings and $\kappa=2^{\aleph_0}$ (which then implies $\kappa=\aleph_2$).

Let's focus on subclasses of ccc forcings.

We can force Martin's Axiom for only $\sigma$-centered forcings, or other subclasses, and there is a clear hierarchy here. For example,
$$\operatorname{FA}_{2^{\aleph_0}}(\textrm{ccc})\implies\operatorname{FA}_{2^{\aleph_0}}(\sigma\textrm{-centered})\implies\operatorname{FA}_{2^{\aleph_0}}(\sigma\textrm{-linked}).$$

Of course, there are many, many other subclasses that one can consider.

> **Question.** Is there any work on separating the various forcing axioms for subclasses of ccc forcings? For example, is it consistent that $\operatorname{FA}_{\aleph_2}(\sigma\textrm{-linked})$ holds, but only $\operatorname{FA}_{\aleph_1}(\sigma\textrm{-centered})$ holds, and $\operatorname{FA}_{\aleph_1}(\textrm{ccc})$ fails altogether?

(And I cannot stress this enough, the choice of subclasses was entirely arbitrary, and any other subclasses of ccc forcings are of interest here.)

Comment: The way you wrote it, PFA is compatible with CH (in particular it doesn't imply $\kappa=\aleph_2$). To make things nontrivial we should just always require that $\kappa$ is at least $\aleph_2$ when talking about $\mathrm{FA}_\kappa$ (this applies to your question too).

Comment: You're right. There's also some discrepancy in the example I gave in the question itself. I'll fix this later when I'm at a computer again. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm not sure whether or not the standard notation is that $\operatorname{FA}_\kappa$ means there is a filter meeting every $\kappa$ dense sets, or if I should just add the requirement that $\kappa>\aleph_1$.

Answer (score 7):

[This paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm141/fm14114.pdf) seems to be the sort of thing you're looking for:

> J. H. Barnett, "Weak variants of Martin's Axiom," *Fundamenta Mathematicae* **141** (1992), pp. 61-73.

The abstract is pretty short and to the point: *A hierarchy of weak variants of Martin's Axiom is extended and shown to be strict.*

There is a nice picture on page 2 showing the hierarchy of axioms considered in the paper. At the top of the author's hierarchy is MA, and at the bottom is MA(sigma-centered).

Along the same lines, there is some related material on page 339 of Kunen's newer Set Theory book (the one from 2011). He defines *MAK* to mean that MA holds for all posets with Property K, and he defines *MAP* to mean that MA holds for all posets with $\aleph_1$ as a pre-calibre. He then proves

> **Theorem:** There is a (finite-support iterated) forcing notion that forces MAK and MAP, but does not kill Suslin trees.

In particular, if you iterate over a ground model with Suslin trees then MA must fail in the extension, even though MAK and MAP both hold.

Comment: Thanks! That certainly looks like this is the direction I was thinking about. I will look at it more carefully tomorrow. I was hoping for a richer separation structure, but I am aware that separating more than two levels of cardinal invariants is usually hard.

Answer (score 3):

Another reference is the paper "[On partial orderings having precalibre-$\aleph_1$ and fragments of Martin's axiom](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05500)" by Bagaria-Shelah.